# Orderby Not Working

Tags: templates

I have a channel field named {board_sort_order} and I limited the entry to Integer. I am trying to use that field to order the dynamic listing on the template. I have tried everything and search ALL of Google (almost, anyway) and cannot get the sort order to take effect.

Here is my template tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="leaders" disable="pagination" search:is_board="Yes" orderby=(int){board_sort_order} sort="asc"}
```

I have tried it with and without the implicit PHP cast of (int).

Also if I leave out "sort="asc." I just get the records in the reverse order of how they were input.

ANY help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you have a syntax error in your tag. Try this:

`{exp:channel:entries channel="leaders" disable="pagination" search:is_board="Yes" orderby="board_sort_order" sort="asc"}`

Comment: I had tried that as well but tried it again ... still no luck

Comment: Does the field show up properly for each entry on the front-end when put between the tag pair?

Comment: I had a typo in my answer. Try the new example.

Comment: YES!!!! no (int) & no curly braces & double quotes = magic   {exp:channel:entries channel="leaders" disable="pagination" search:is_board="Yes" orderby="board_sort_order" sort="asc"}